# Why is beautifulsoup not returning data elements?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've tried many things to return the data on this page: https://www.hebban.nl/rank . For some reason it's not returning any data point, after many tries.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is a quick example to get (in theory the author and title on the page).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send a GET request to the URL
url = "https://www.hebban.nl/rank"
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the book titles, authors, and image url links
books = soup.find_all('div', class_='row-fluid')
for book in books:
    title = book.find('a', class_='neutral').text.strip()
    author = book.find('span', class_='author').text.strip()


    print(title + ' by ' + author)
    print('Image URL: ' + img_url)
```

Comment: ChatGPT won't help you learn coding imho. And regarding your question probably the page is SPA, which is empty when python is trying to read it, because the JS framework didn't populate the DOM yet.

Comment: fair point - I've only used it to see if it can help me solve any errors I run into. I don't think its SPA though, it's a static table that updates each day. Do you have any recommendation on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place. - Simply print your response / soup*

---

You have to set a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to your request to avoid a first block by the server and get `beautifulsoup` find something you are looking for:

```
response = requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some agent'})
```

Also take a closer look to your selections and note that you have to select the #1 book separatly, because it will not fit the same selection.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send a GET request to the URL
url = "https://www.hebban.nl/rank"
response = requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some agent'})

# Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the book titles, authors, and image url links
books = soup.find_all('div', class_='item')
for book in books:
    title = book.h3.text.strip()
    author = book.find('span', class_='author').text.strip()
    img_url = book.img.get('data-src')
    
    print(title + ' by ' + author)
    print('Image URL: ' + img_url)
```

###### Output

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
2 by Raoul de Jong
Image URL: https://static.hebban.nl/covers/00001122/thumb/DEF%20omslag%20-%20Boto%20Banja.png
3 by Freida McFadden
Image URL: https://static.hebban.nl/covers/00001063/thumb/9789032520267.jpg
4 by Helen Fields
Image URL: https://static.hebban.nl/covers/00001062/thumb/9789026360787.jpg
5 by Thomas Olde Heuvelt
Image URL: https://static.hebban.nl/covers/00001032/thumb/9789022591116.jpeg
...
```

Comment: thank you @HedgeHog - this works and I now understand how to proceed and use in future cases. Appreciate you!

Comment: one more question; what's the easiest way to deal with non-existing data points in a list for some image URLs or genres - that cause a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error?

Comment: let's say out of the 10 titles 1 doesn't have a genre listed... I don't want the entire code to stop / get an error but just pass a N/A for example

Comment: Simply check with statement if element exists before apply any method, if not set to specific value or just None